# C++ operator overloading called as function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, unary-operator

I'm experimenting with operator overloading and found something that I cannot explain:

WeekDays.h

```
using namespace std;
enum DAYS
{
    MON,
    TUE,
    WED,
    THU,
    FRY,
    SAT,
    SUN
};

DAYS operator+(DAYS&a,DAYS &b)
{
    printf("Binary+ called\n");
    return (DAYS)(((unsigned int)a+(unsigned int)b)%7);
}

//Increment 3
DAYS operator+(DAYS&a)
{
    printf("Unary+ called\n");
    return (DAYS)(((unsigned int)a+3)%7);
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream&o, DAYS &a)
{
    switch(a){
    case MON: o<<"MON"; break;
    case TUE: o<<"TUE"; break;
    case WED: o<<"WED"; break;
    case THU: o<<"THU"; break;
    case FRY: o<<"FRY"; break;
    case SAT: o<<"SAT"; break;
    case SUN: o<<"SUN"; break;
    }
    return o;
};
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "WeekDays.h"
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    DAYS a=MON; //=0
    DAYS b=TUE; //=1
    cout<< +a       <<endl;
    cout<< +b       <<endl;
    cout<< +(a,b)   <<endl;
    cout<< (a+b)    <<endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

Output is

```
Unary+ called
3
Unary+ called
4
Unary+ called
4
Binary+ called
1
```

Why is +(a,b) evaluated as unary operator +b ? I've failed to explain this.

Link to relevant thread [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/16615725) .
I'm Using VisualStudio 2012.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `(a,b)` you happen to invoke the odd ["comma" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work), which evaluates first a, then b, and finally returns b.

You could call your operator by spelling it out as `operator+(a,b)`. (Here the comma is a separator for the parameters, and *not* the comma operator).

Comment: Since both unary and binary + operators have higher precedence I would expect `+()` to be evaluated first, thus interpreting the comma as separator instead of comma operator. How does the compiler decide that `+(a,b)` is unary+?

Comment: @LorenzoBelli parentheses changes the order of evaluation: `+(a,b)` first evaluates the content of the parentheses and then the unary `+` while +a,b first evaluates `+a` then the comma and then the b.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the link http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

unary plus, aka +a

```
T::operator+() const;   
T operator+(const T &a);
```

addition, aka a + b

```
T::operator+(const T2 &b) const;    
T T operator+(const T &a, const T2 &b);
```

With your overloaded operator+(a,b) you should get at least this warning:
warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]